# Only CocoaPod schemes are available in Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have a problem running my application in Xcode. Suddenly the only "schemes" that are available are CocoaPod schemes. The project scheme doesn't show. Any suggestions?

Comment: Regenerate the scheme? Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes > Autocreate Schemes Now...

Comment: Check to make sure your Xcode project file doesn't have any broken syntax. This can happen in merges (sometimes without even a conflict)

Answer (score 0):

1- Go to your project directory and on .xcproject or .xcworkspace file do a right click > show package contents and remove the data inside xcuserdata directory. Quit and relaunch Xcode.